# pasting embeddings/homeomorphisms defined over closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and that $X = A \cup B$ for some closed subsets $A$ and $B$.

We assume that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is an injective mapping such that
$$
f_{|A} : A \to f(A), \quad f_{|B} : B \to f(B)
$$
are homeomorphisms.

Thanks to the pasting lemma, I can show that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Is it true that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is an embedding, that is,
$$
f : X \to f(X)
$$
is a homeomorphisms?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^2$:
\begin{align*}
A &= \{0\} \times [0, 1] \\
B & = \{1\} \times (0, 1] \\
C & = (0, 1] \times \{0\} \\
X & = A \cup B \\
Y & = A \cup C
\end{align*}
So $X$ is the disjoint union of a closed interval $A$ and a half-open interval $B$, both of which are closed as subsets of $X$.
While $Y$ is $L$-shaped ($C$ is not a closed subset of $Y$).
Now define $f : X \to Y$ by:

$$
f((x, y)) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
      (x, y)\quad \mbox{if $x = 0$, i.e., $(x, y) \in A$}\\
      (y, 0)\quad \mbox{otherwise, i.e., $(x, y) \in B$}
   \end{array}\right.
$$

So $f$ acts as the identity on $A$ and as the obvious homeomorphism from $B$ to $C$.
Then $f$ is injective, and $f_{|A}$ and $f_{|B}$ are both homeomorphisms, but $f$ is not an embedding because its inverse is not continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Aside: if you make the additional assumption that $X$ is compact, then your result will hold.